# Не удаётся преобразовать IEnumerable к List

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq, ienumerable

Выполняю задание, обучаясь работе с Linq, но столкнулся с проблемой.

Задание таково:

> **У вас есть список строк, в каждой из которой написаны две координаты точки (X, Y), разделенные пробелом.
> Реализуйте метод ParsePoints в одно LINQ-выражение. Постарайтесь не использовать функцию преобразования строки в число более одного раза.**

Дан следующий код:

```
public static void Main()
{


// Функция тестирования ParsePoints

foreach (var point in ParsePoints(new[] { "1 -2", "-3 4", "0 2" }))
    Console.WriteLine(point.X + " " + point.Y);
foreach (var point in ParsePoints(new List<string> { "+01 -0042" }))
    Console.WriteLine(point.X + " " + point.Y);
}

public class Point
{
    public Point(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
    public int X, Y;
}
```

Далее для решения автоматически был собран следующий метод:

```
    public static List<Point> ParsePoints(IEnumerable<string> lines)
{
    return lines
        .Select(...)
        ...
}
```

Вот моя попытка решить задание:

```
static List<Point> ParsePoints(IEnumerable<string> lines)
        {
            return lines
                .Select(str => Array.ConvertAll(str.Split(' '), int.Parse).Select((x, y) => new Point(x, y)))
                .ToList();
        }
```

После всё тело метода обводится красным подчёркнутым контуром со следующей ошибкой:

> **Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "System.Collections.Generic.List <System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Tasks2.Programs.Point>>" в "System.Collections.Generic.List<Tasks.Programs.Point>".**

Не понимаю, из-за чего вылазит данная ошибка. Уже несколько дней убил на решение, прошу помощи.

Comment: `Tasks2.Programs.Point` & `Tasks.Programs.Point` - разберитесь с классами у которых одинаковое название

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уберите конфликт в названии и не делайте несколько классов с одинаковыми именами в решении.

```
public class MyPoint
{
    public MyPoint(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
    public int X, Y;
}
```

Метод получился такой, вы были близко

```
static MyPoint[] ParsePoints(string[] lines)
{
    return lines
        .Select(line => line.Split().Select(int.Parse).ToArray())
        // или (line => Array.ConvertAll(line.Split(), int.Parse))
        .Select(x => new MyPoint(x[0], x[1]))
        .ToArray();
}
```

Проверка такая

```
foreach (var point in ParsePoints(new[] { "1 -2", "-3 4", "0 2" }))
    Console.WriteLine(point.X + " " + point.Y);
```

Вывод в консоль такой

```
1 -2
-3 4
0 2
```

Comment: `Реализуйте метод ParsePoints в одно LINQ-выражение.`

Comment: @tym32167 исправлено, спасибо

Comment:  (нужно ещё 12 символов...)

Comment: Спасибо огромное, вы очень помогли!